# How is the sintaxis to use ignore_dup_key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to ignore duplicates when I insert rows in a many to many relationship table, but all the examples that I find is modifying the key in the table.

I would like to know if there is some way to set this only for the inserts that I want to do, something like that:

```
insert into Table(IDA, IDB) VALUES(1,2) ignore_dup_key = ON;
```

Thanks.

Comment: No you can't do this. ignore_dup_key is an index option, not a query hint. What are you really trying to accomplish? Seems that using a where clause would be a lot simpler.

Comment: I have a many to many relationship table, I want ignore duplicates, if I try to insert (1,2) inside a transaction, I want to continue if other process has inserted this value in the table.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore duplicate". Do you mean you want to allow them into the table? Or do you mean you don't want to insert them? If you want to allow them then you need to adjust your index. If you don't want to insert them then I would suggest using a NOT EXISTS in a where clause for your insert.

Comment: Short answer - no, this is not a statement-level option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just edited this answer after @Alvaro Garcia Comment

```
insert into Table(IDA, IDB) 
SELECT T.IDA, T.IDB 
FROM (SELECT 1 as IDA, 2 as IDB) T
LEFT JOIN Table T2 ON T.IDA = T2.IDA AND T.IDB = T2.IDB
WHERE T2.IDA is null
```

before I was just checking existence and then insert.

Comment: In this case between the if and the insert some could insert the row and to have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

"ignore_dup_key = ON" is a property that you define when creating an index. It is not a query hint.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_table 
    ON dbo.Table (KeyColumn)
    WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON) ON [PRIMARY];
```